# How to customize Swagger UI in .NET Core 6.0

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetcore v6.5. How to align endpoint summary to right side corner?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: may be this helps you https://ostranme.github.io/swagger-ui-themes/

Comment: have you checked my solution?

Answer (score -1):

Use one of the themes I suggested and modify it. This makes what you want;

```
.swagger-ui .opblock .opblock-summary-description {
   font-size: 13px;
   text-align: right;
   padding-right: 35px;
   -webkit-box-flex: 1;
   -ms-flex: 1;
   flex: 1;
   font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
   color: #3b4151
}
```